# How can I set window-transparency in codelite?

Tags: linux, window, transparency, x11, codelite

Is it possible to set window transparency in codelite, for example for the output or workspace view?
Is there a fast option to hardcode this since this feature seems to e missing and how platform dependent would that be?

I use xubuntu.

Comment: please don't ask suggestions on SO!!!

Comment: It is not a suggestion it is a question. There is the possibility that someone made it work for themselves, hence the question.

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have a solution write about it in the answer box provided. Don't just edit the word "solved" into the question. This just causes the question to hang around in the unanswered queue. (Or just delete the whole question)

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it since it is something that is applicable to a whole set of similar questions. I'd be happy to find an answer like this instead of wasting time researching something rather minor but neat. It's in the answer box now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I followed the instructions on "Per Application Transparency" in this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Per_Application_Transparency) which uses [Devil's Pie](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie): to grap and change window behavior. Follow the instructions and place this into your "opacity.ds" :

```
( if
    ( and
            ( contains ( application_name ) "codelite" )
            ( or
                    ( is ( window_name ) "Output View" )
                    ( is ( window_name ) "Workspace View" )
            )
    )

    ( begin
            ( spawn_async (str "transset-df -i " (window_xid) " 0.55" ))
    ))
```

This makes the "Output view" and the "Worspace View" transparent(if detached) with an alpha of 0.55. Change the value to your liking.